# Elmah stops sending email after a while

Tags: iis-7.5, elmah

We have an Elmah configured to send error notification emails to us whenever something is wrong. It all worked great for a while but we're noticing that sometimes Elmah would just stop sending error notifications, but still logs the error as XML.

So to verify, we have a test page which generates uncaught 500 server error. If we did an IIS reset and try the page, Elmah would correctly logs and send the notification error. However after a while (we're still unsure of how long or when it stopped working.) Elmah would only log the file without sending email notifications.

So far we have ruled out SMTP server not sending Elmah notifications because when we trigger the 500 server error while Elmah is in a bad state, there's no entry in SMTP server log at all.

In summary, the symptoms are as follows:

1. When Elmah is in a bad state, it'll stop generating Email notification but continue logging error in XML file.
2. After IIS Reset, everything goes back to normal. (Though we do have scheduled app recycle everyday, but that doesn't seem to help in this situation.)
3. The bad state seems to be triggered by whenever we overridethe existing binary to a newer release without restarting IIS. However, the 500 server error test indicates that Elmah sometimes goes into bad state, sometimes don't.

Is anyone observing similar symptoms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you ever get this fixed?

http://groups.google.com/group/elmah/browse_thread/thread/51d24dd6c94e6dc2

Seems to be a similar problem and says:

Got it.... it's the JScript error filter. . If I strip the filter out, it works just 
fine.

Comment: Yeah we ended up just use the C# and compile it with our code instead of JScript filter, its a shame though since JScript can be easily modified.